Upper bound $R(a, b, c) < 3^{a+b+c}$ for Ramsey Number
How can we prove that $R(a, b, c) \le 3^{a+b+c}$?
I understand the logic behind proving lower Ramsey bounds: $R(a, b, c) > N$ - we should give an example of construction on $N$ vertices that would violate the definition of Ramsey Number. But what is the common way to prove upper bounds like this I have?
I've tried to use recurrent inequalities but this way gives nothing here

Do you know the way to prove the upper bound $R(k,\ell)<2^{k+\ell}$ for two-color Ramsey numbers?

@CarlSchildkraut, nope

It might be worthwhile to read a proof of this (you can find a proof on the Wikipedia page for Ramsey's theorem), or to try to come up with it yourself. A hint: induct on $k+\ell$.

@CarlSchildkraut, I guess I don't have enough experience on working with Ramsey Numbers and can't prove induction step. Could you please enlighten me how to prove it?

@CarlSchildkraut, I've found this question. it solves my task, nevertheless I'd like to solve it without this linked post. (the problem is that in my task there are 3 distinct arguments of Ramsey Number and I can't come up with an induction step because of it)

@CarlSchildkraut, I've just proved upper bound $R(k, l) < 2^{k+l}$ using binomial coefficients bound for Ramsey Number and the fact that sum of bin coefficients is $2^n$. Should I understand how to prove my 3 colors task now? :)

@CarlSchildkraut, I guess now I understand everything: using your bound with power of 2 we get that $R(a, b, c) < 2^{2^{a+b}+c}$ and it's obviously bigger than $3^{a+b+c}$.

Along the hint given by CarlSchildkraut, we have $r(a,b,c)\le r(a-1,b,c)+r(a,b-1,c)+r(a,b,c-1)$.
By induction, we have $$r(a,b,c)\le \binom{a+b+c-3}{a-1,b-1,c-1}=\frac{(a+b+c-3)!}{(a-1)!(b-1)!(c-1)!}, $$
where the right hand side is the multinomial coefficient of $x_1^{a-1}x_2^{b-1}x_3^{c-1}$ in $(x_1+x_2+x_3)^{a+b+c-3}$.
Take $x_1=x_2=x_3=1$, we have $r(a,b,c)\le 3^{a+b+c-3}$.
